# using inlineframe in wicket to make a popup for print

Tags: wicket

I want to use inlinframe to show a popup preview print page and here is my problem:

Java:

```
Form form = new Form("form");
form.setOutputMarkupId(true);
form.add(new AjaxSubmitLink("test") {
    @Override
    protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget art, Form<?> form) {
        containerPrint.add(/*another inlineframe*/)
        art.addComponent(containerPrint);
    }
});
add(form);
```

Html:

```
<form wicket:id="form">
    <input type="button" wicket:id="test"></input>
</form>
<div wicket:id="page" style="width: 0px;height: 0px">
    <iframe wicket:id="printPage" width="0px" height="0px">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

I want to replace inlineiframe with another inlineiframe by clicking test button
but by clicking button im getting this problem

```
WicketMessage: org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: component form:panel:panel:panel:mcGridViewInfo:GridViewInfo:form:<b>test not found on page</b> ir.mersad.ui.authenticationAndAuthorization.Office[id = 1], listener interface = [RequestListenerInterface name=IActivePageBehaviorListener, method=public abstract void org.apache.wicket.behavior.IBehaviorListener.onRequest()]

Root cause:

org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: component form:panel:panel:panel:mcGridViewInfo:GridViewInfo:form:test not found on page ir.mersad.ui.authenticationAndAuthorization.Office[id = 1], listener interface = [RequestListenerInterface name=IActivePageBehaviorListener, method=public abstract void org.apache.wicket.behavior.IBehaviorListener.onRequest()]
at org.apache.wicket.request.AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.resolveListenerInterfaceTarget(AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.java:427)
at org.apache.wicket.request.AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.resolveRenderedPage(AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.java:472)
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WebRequestCycleProcessor.resolve(WebRequestCycleProcessor.java:144)
at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.step(RequestCycle.java:1339)
at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.steps(RequestCycle.java:1465)
at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.request(RequestCycle.java:545)
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doGet(WicketFilter.java:486)
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:319)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Complete stack:

org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.request.InvalidUrlException: org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: component form:panel:panel:panel:mcGridViewInfo:GridViewInfo:form:test not found on page ir.mersad.ui.authenticationAndAuthorization.Office[id = 1], listener interface = [RequestListenerInterface name=IActivePageBehaviorListener, method=public abstract void org.apache.wicket.behavior.IBehaviorListener.onRequest()]
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WebRequestCycleProcessor.resolve(WebRequestCycleProcessor.java:262)
at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.step(RequestCycle.java:1339)
at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.steps(RequestCycle.java:1465)
at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.request(RequestCycle.java:545)
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doGet(WicketFilter.java:486)
```

I already know that the problem is with:

```
container.add(new InlineFrame("printPage", new EmptyPage()));
```

cause its work fine when i replaced it with a label but i dont know whats the problem

Answer (score 2):

It's not totally clear what the problem is (some code is obviously missing). It looks like you are adding a new component instead of replacing the old one.

Try it like this:

```
public class HomePage extends WebPage {
    private InlineFrame iframe = new InlineFrame("iframe", new OtherPage());

    public HomePage() {
        iframe.setOutputMarkupId(true);

        Form form = new Form("form");
        form.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        form.add(new AjaxSubmitLink("test") {
            @Override
            protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget art, Form<?> form) {
                InlineFrame newIframe = new InlineFrame("iframe", new OtherPage());
                iframe.replaceWith(newIframe);
                iframe = newIframe;
                art.add(iframe);
            }
        });
        add(form, iframe);
    }
}
```

It's important to

- call `replaceWith` so that Wicket can update the component tree accordingly
- change your reference of iframe to point to the new component

Answer (score 0):

Simply Replace previous frame

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            InlineFrame newIframe = new InlineFrame("iframe", PersonalInformationPage.class);
            iframe.replaceWith(newIframe);
            iframe = newIframe;
            target.add(iframe);
        }
```